# Deleting a sign at the end of the SPECIFIC lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm a rather unexperienced Notepad++ user, and I practically do nothing more than copy-paste different regex queries that are posted here - to clean things such as game's server logs. Now I have found a problem that couldn't be solved through Stackoverflow research.

I would like to delete a last letter (sign) at the end of every line, but ONLY if it's a "!" Long story short, I want to have a regex query that would get me rid of something like that:

```
Jedi=Knight=Virdu: Hello everyone.!
Jedi=Master=Yvan: <bows his head, barely keeping his eyes open, like he is about to fall asleep>!
Padawan=Acodin has joined the spectators.
Padawan=Vic has defeated: Training Droid [NPC].
Jedi=Knight=Rus: Is something wrong, Master Yvan?!
```

and transform it into:

```
Jedi=Knight=Virdu: Hello everyone.
Jedi=Master=Yvan: <bows his head, barely keeping his eyes open, like he is about to fall asleep>
Padawan=Acodin has joined the spectators.
Padawan=Vic has defeated: Training Droid [NPC].
Jedi=Knight=Rus: Is something wrong, Master Yvan?
```

Thanks ahead for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for "!$" (matches all lines that end with "!"), and replace it with nothing. So you just paste log to notepad, type ctrl^f as usual, go to replace window, type !$  into the first box and leave the second blank.

Comment: Damn, that was easy. Sorry for taking your time - I just didn't have any knowledge.